# Splitting Data within a <tr> using Jquery and no spaces or characters

Tags: jquery

I'd like to split data within a `<tr>` using something like a line break or a div but haven't had any luck looking up the syntax. Basically I have a lot of data within a single cell that I need to be able to edit in separate chunks to sql server. Below is code showing the php/html and what I tried with jquery. Each $header[] is just a piece of data from an array from a sql query.

Is there any way to use `<br>` as a split in this situation?

`<td>".$header[11]."<br>".$header[12]."<br>".$header[13]."<br>".$header[14]."<br>".$header[15]."<br>".$header[16]."<br>".$header[17]."<br>".$header[18]."<br>".$header[19]."<br>".$header[20]."<br>".$header[21]."<br>".$header[22]."</td>`

`var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); var $split = $row.find("td").eq(4).text().split("<br>"); var $name = $split[0];`

The .eq(4) is necessary because this is the 5th , the cells before this could just be split with a space with no issues, this cell cannot be split with a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, wrap the header content with a div. Give each div a class that represents the content of that div. I have field-name in here as place holders but you will want to use the proper names.

```
echo "<td><div class='name'>{$header[11]}</div>{$header[12]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[13]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[14]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[15]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[16]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[17]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[18]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[19]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[20]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[21]}</div><div class='field-name'>{$header[22]}</div></td>";
```

Then in jquery you can reference the data by the class name

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(4);
var $name = $row.find(".name").text();
```